# Mapear no Django tabelas geradas dinamicamente por outra aplicação

Tags: python, postgresql, django

Irei desenvolver uma aplicação com Django em que será necessário consultar dados em um banco de dados que é alimentado por um ERP (desktop).

Esse ERP gera algumas tabelas de movimentação adicionando ao final do nome da tabela o mês e o ano, como uma espécie de particionamento, exemplo: `financeiro0718`, `financeiro0818`, `financeiro0918`, etc.

Essas tabelas possuem a mesma estrutura de colunas e tipos de dados, a diferença é apenas o nome. Minha intenção é de ter apenas um model mapeando essas tabelas para não ficar com uma quantidade enorme de classes com código repetido no meu projeto.

Como posso realizar o mapeamento dessas tabelas no Django de uma forma que eu possa ter um model `Financeiro` e o ORM poder consultar os dados nas tabelas correspondentes?

Comment: Creio que isto aqui poderá te ajudar: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/sql/

Comment: Então @GiovanniNunes, até conhecia o método `raw`, é que minha ideia era deixar o ORM gerar o SQL, principalmente porque a aplicação poderá ser utilizada com Oracle ou MSSQL.

Comment: Achei que você apenas consumiria as tabelas, sem possibilidade de mexer na estrutura.

Comment: É isso mesmo @GiovanniNunes, em muitos casos a sintaxe do `SELECT` é diferente de um SGDB para outro, por isso minha intenção é usar o ORM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode explícitar o nome da tabela no banco SQL preenchendo o campo `db_table` nos metadados de um model. Numa declaração convencional, os metadados ficam ficam dentro da classe aninhada com o nome "Meta" -

Então uma forma de criar vários modelos dinâmicamente, cada um apontando para uma tabela, é criar esses modelos dinâmicamente com chamadas a `type`, mudando os dados necessários - você pode armazenar esses modelos num dicionário, e assim poderá ter acesso aos mesmos em runtime.

Se isso for feito em código `top level` - isso é, executado quando o arquivio `models.py` for carregado, é quase certo que vai funcionar. Talvez funcione de forma lazy, com os models sendo criados dinamicamente a medida que forem necessários também - mas pode ser que não, se o Django executar alguma ação do ORM na hora que carrega as tabelas.

```
from django.db import model

class BaseFinanceiro(models.Model):
     # declare os campos normalmente
     class Meta:
          abstract = True

tabelas_extras = "financeiro0718 financeiro0818 financeiro0918 ...".split()
# acima, é só uma forma com menos digitação de criar uma lista

modelos = {}
for nome in tabelas_extras:
     meta = type('Meta', (), {'db_table': nome})
     modelos[nome] = type(nome, (BaseFinanceiro,), {'Meta': meta})
```

Claro que só usei o "nome" como string por que foi o exemplo que você deu - o acesso pode ficar ainda mais direto se você usar como chaves de cionário em "modelos" um par de valores "mes, ano" (fica uma tupla em Python:  modelos[9, 18] - ou mesmo um objeto datetime.date) - mas aí, claro, depende de como você vai acessar esses modelos no restante do código.

Comment: precisei definir a `BaseFinanceiro` como classe abstrata e o atributo `__module__` porque gerou um `KeyError` no meu teste. Num geral funcionou como você sugeriu, já me deu uma luz aqui. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Legal-  vi que você tinha sugerido uma edição - como mudava o código, outros moderadores do S.O. não tinham aprovado - arrumei agora.